# When to use Admin model_delete/model_save and Model delete/save?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Just curious as to the best practices for using save/delete in Model versus delete_model/save_model in ModelAdmin. Is one preferred over the other?

In my particular case, I have a Document model with a JSON field that holds a bunch of metadata (name:value pairs) for Documents (photos, pdfs, etc). The metadata is defined in other models (MetaData for names and MetaDataValue for the value(s)), so I can change the metadata names and values at run time.

When an existing MetaData name or value changes or is deleted, I need to "scrub" the metadata stored in the Document model to change/delete the metadata names/values to keep them in sync with what is defined in the MetaData and MetaDataValue models. All these changes are done through the Admin screens.

Would it be more appropriate to use model_save and model_delete in the Admin or save and delete in the respective models? Functionally, it does not matter as far as I can see. I am just wondering if there is a preferred way, or a more "django idiomatic" way to do this.

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin functions should only be used when you want to handle something that's being saved during an admin site-only flow. Overriding `save` and `delete` are for when you want the actions to occur for any save or delete.

However, I'd actually suggest you look at the [pre_save, post_save, pre_delete and post_delete signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/). They are hooks for you to manage the data in a more extensible way.